# Flink - Cannot Submit New Job

Tags: upload, apache-flink

Cannot seem to be able to upload new jobs to Flink instance - or to get the web UI to do much.

Beginner, using Flink 1.4.0 on RedHat Linux 2.6, Java 1.8.0_45.

I was able to start the local cluster and see the web interface at `http://hostname:8081`. Following the [Quickstart](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html) tutorial, I was able to start the job, send text into it and see the word counts in the log. However, the web interface does not seem to work: when the job is running, I cannot see the "Running Jobs" counter display 1 (it shows 0). When I try to upload a JAR using the web interface, nothing happens, and the JAR is not listed under "Uploaded JARs". The jobmanager and taskmanager logs do not show that I am uploading anything. I can upload the JAR via `curl`, and it says `{"status": "success", "filename": "SomeUID_SocketWindowWordCount.jar"}` - but I still cannot see that JAR as "Uploaded"

What am I missing?

Update: One day later, the "Submit new Job" page correctly shows that I have submitted half a dozen JARs. The "Completed Jobs" page still does not show anything.

Comment: How did you run the example? Did you used `./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --port 9000`?

Comment: Yes. I followed the Quickstart to the letter.In the log, I can see the word count (so the job is running), but the web UI does not show any running jobs, and the job upload does not work either. Maybe the web server tries to communicate to the job processor on ports that are blocked in my corporate environment?

Comment: Did you tried to run `flink list`. This should give you a list of all running flink jobs. If that also doesn't work I would check the logs of the job manager to find some warnings when submitting the job ...